# Angular JS server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular js. I am using Mean Stack Method. My controller.js file has the following code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl',['$scope','$http',function MyCtrl($scope,$http){
    console.log("hello from controller");
    $http.get('/pointList');

    person1 = {
        name:'roni',
        email:'roni@gmail.com',
    };
    person2 = {

        name:'abhijit',
        email:'abhijit@gmail.com',


    };
    person3 = {
        name: 'amit',
        email: 'amit@gmail.com',

    };
  var pointList =[person1,person2,person3];
    $scope.pointList = pointList;
}]);
```

My server.js has the following code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname +'/public'));

app.post('/pointList',function(req, res){
    console.log("Hey ! received get request");

});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("server running on port 3000");
```

I am unable to receive the get request.
Thanks

Comment: do you have a page at `http://localhost:3000/pointList`?

Answer (score 1):

You are firing a `get` request from front-end while receiving a `post` call at backend. Change the `app.post` to `app.get`

```
app.post('/pointList',function(req, res){
    console.log("Hey ! received get request");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/pointList',function(req, res){
    console.log("Hey ! received get request");

});
```

try changing to the above

Comment: Do you get any errors? And if not what do you get in response?

Comment: Error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)